# Повышение цены за домен reg.ru

Tags: домен

В прошлом году купил домен себе. За сколько покупал точно не помню. Мне казалось, что это было рублей 300. Сейчас подумал продлить и вот я офигел. Выкатили 1200 червонцев. Не фига себе подумал я и задумался, что будет далее. Каким образом формируются цены на доменные имена и можно ли избежать повышения цены в следующем году?

Comment: А там разве не у всех первый год как бы рекламный дешевый, а со второго года цена совсем другая? Я как-то хотел домен купить, но этап фигня меня остановила )

Comment: Почти у всех первый год 150-300 рублей. Со второго года по 600. Посмотри на 2 domains ru. У них второй год тоже дороже, но дешевле регру потому что без документов

Comment: 1200 (= почему-то

Comment: И, да. Уважаемые закрывающие? Почему по Вашему мнению невозможно дать объективный ответ? Вы ошибаетесь, кажется.

Comment: https://www.reg.ru/company/prices/#expanders=domain,cis вот тут при наведении мышкой появляется цена продления.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На третий год не повышают. Цены можно найти в колонке продление тарифов регистратора.

[reg.ru/company/prices/#expanders=domain,cis](https://reg.ru/company/prices/#expanders=domain,cis) вот тут при наведении мышкой появляется цена продления.

Цена второго года также написана мелким шрифтом при покупке. Сам хотел ругаться, но в оферте все есть.

Снизить цену можно сменой регистратора на тот же регру, но по другой партнерке.